# Is it necessary to convert to LIBSVM format

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision, svm, libsvm

I have been working on libsvm recently. I faced a problem with the pred label. All the values outputted were 1. It did not identify negative data at all. I didn't convert to LIBSVM format( meaning to say: i didn't use libsvmwrite at all). I created the label myself. So my question, is it important to convert to the LIBSVM format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From matlab you don't need to use svmwrite. Just use svmtrain, and svmpredict. The Labels can be any number, it will convert everything automatically. Your problem comes from somewhere else.

Comment: i have been trying for one week... and labels are all 1... tried both the bioinformatics toolbox as well as libsvm

Comment: Is there both types of labels in the training set?

Comment: When you test on your training data, is it same?

Comment: Did you make sure you are scaling the test data with the same parameters used to scale the training data?

Comment: i solved already... i didn't scale in the first place... hence the pred label were wrong

Comment: Please help to answer me on libsvm data format as well, I got stuck now with it since too new for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666851/how-to-train-image-pixel-data-in-libsvm-format-to-use-for-recognition-with-jav