# How to train image (pixel) data in libsvm format to use for recognition with Java

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm

I want to make a Java application to recognize characters by using libsvm but when get into this, I do not understand how could I train the image data to use with libsvm?

Recently to learn it, I made a test with [existing data:](http://ask.osify.com/qa/311)

I have also create `32x32` based training image data by convert each pixel to `0,1` but I don't know if it could use to create libsvm training data format?
And also how the libsvm testing data created?

Example of converted image pixels `(0,1)`:

```
00000000000001111000000000000000
00000000000011111110000000000000
00000000001111111111000000000000
00000001111111111111100000000000
00000001111111011111100000000000
00000011111110000011110000000000
00000011111110000000111000000000
00000011111110000000111100000000
00000011111110000000011100000000
00000011111110000000011100000000
00000011111100000000011110000000
00000011111100000000001110000000
00000011111100000000001110000000
00000001111110000000000111000000
00000001111110000000000111000000
00000001111110000000000111000000
00000001111110000000000111000000
00000011111110000000001111000000
00000011110110000000001111000000
00000011110000000000011110000000
00000001111000000000001111000000
00000001111000000000011111000000
00000001111000000000111110000000
00000001111000000001111100000000
00000000111000000111111000000000
00000000111100011111110000000000
00000000111111111111110000000000
00000000011111111111110000000000
00000000011111111111100000000000
00000000001111111110000000000000
00000000000111110000000000000000
00000000000011000000000000000000
 0
00000000000001111111110000000000
00000000001111111111111000000000
00000000011111111111111100000000
00000000011111111111111100000000
00000000011111111111111110000000
00000001111111111111111100000000
00000000111110000011111100000000
00000000000000000001111100000000
00000000000000000001111100000000
00000000000000000001111100000000
00000000000000000011111000000000
00000000000000000111111000000000
00000000000000000111111000000000
00000000000000000111111000000000
00000000000000001111110000000000
00000000011111111111111111000000
00000000111111111111111111100000
00000000111111111111111111100000
00000000111111111111111111100000
00000001111111111111111110000000
00000001111111111110000000000000
00000001111111111110000000000000
00000000111111111110000000000000
00000000000011111000000000000000
00000000000011111000000000000000
00000000000011111000000000000000
00000000000111111000000000000000
00000000000111111000000000000000
00000000001111110000000000000000
00000000011111110000000000000000
00000000001111100000000000000000
00000000001111100000000000000000
 7
```

How to get it for `libsvm (training, testing data)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`libsvm` has a specific data format, each line is a one training/testing vector in the form of

> LABEL INDEX0:VALUE0 INDEX1:VALUE1 ... INDEXN:VALUEN

so in the most "naive" method, you simply convert matrix representation to the row representation by concatenating consequtive rows, so image like

```
010
011
000
```

would become

```
010011000
```

and in the libsvm format (assuming we label it with "5"):

```
5 0:0 1:1 2:0 3:0 4:1 5:1 6:0 7:0 8:0 9:0
```

as libsvm support "sparse" representation, you can ommit values with "0's"

```
5 1:1 4:1 5:1
```

This is a manual way, sample data is located here: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/binary/a1a

The easiest "automatic" way is to represent your data as a .csv format (again - convert data to the row-like format, then to the .csv), which is quite standard method:

> LABEL,PIXEL_0,PIXEL_1,...,PIXEL_N

...

and then use this program for conversion

```
/* convert cvs data to libsvm/svm-light format */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char buf[10000000];
float feature[100000];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;

    if(argc!=2) { fprintf(stderr,"Usage %s filename\n",argv[0]); }
    if((fp=fopen(argv[1],"r"))==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Can't open input file %s\n",argv[1]);
    }

    while(fscanf(fp,"%[^\n]\n",buf)==1)
    {
        int i=0,j;
        char *p=strtok(buf,",");

        feature[i++]=atof(p);

        while((p=strtok(NULL,",")))
            feature[i++]=atof(p);

        //      --i;
        /*
        if ((int) feature[i]==1)
            printf("-1 ");
        else
            printf("+1 ");
        */
        //      printf("%f ", feature[1]);
        printf("%d ", (int) feature[0]);
        for(j=1;j<i;j++)
            printf(" %d:%f",j,feature[j]);


        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Both training and testing files have exactly the same structure, simply split your data in some proportion (3:1 or 9:1) randomly into files `training` and `testing`, but remember to include balanced number of training vectors for each class in each file.

In particular - your data looks a bit like **MNIST** dataset, if it is a case, this is already prepared for libsvm:

http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/multiclass.html

MNIST training: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/multiclass/mnist.scale.bz2

MNIST testing : http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/multiclass/mnist.scale.t.bz2

If it possible with your data, converting your images to the real-valued ones in the [0,1] interval would be more valuable then binary data (which loses much information).

**EDIT**

As an example, if your image is a 8bit greyscale image, then each pixel is in fact a number `v` between 0 and 255. What you are now doing, is some thresholding, setting 1 for `v > T` and 0 for `v <= T`, while mapping these values to real values would give more information to the model. It can be done by simple squashing `v / 255`. As a result, all values are in the `[0,1]` interval, but have also values "in between" like `0.25` etc.

Comment: What should be the method to "converting your images to the real-valued ones in the [0,1]" & how?

Comment: Updated the answer, I simply mean not mapping v->{0,1} but rather to the whole interval [0,1], by for example - dividing the original pixel values (0-255 in case of 8bit image) by the 255.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try around that to see if it would be OK for libsvm

Comment: I have a question, does your solution above is limited to the size of training image data (ex: 32x32 or ) or we can train to any size? Because my data training can not always 32x32

Comment: My solution never mentioned image size. But your data **has to be** in constant size. So if you have different image sizes you need to unify them (rescale to one format), this is a standard procedure to work with raw pixel values in machine learning.

Comment: I haven't made it success to train my data (a character) yet, it's because of my image processing skill limit but your answer is really helping me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @lejlot: I am using LibSVM for classification too. You said "but remember to include balanced number of training vectors for each class in each file" does that mean that in training phase the positive and negative classes or class 1 and class 2 (whichever notation you prefer) should have the same number of images??